# Combine the data from my database and a web service (external API) in a Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, web-services, jpa

I have two entities: Students and Courses. The relationship between these two entities is many-to-many. I maintain a list of courses in my database and provide the admin with the ability to add or remove courses. However, the list of students is obtained from an external API.

How can I merge these two to return a list of students with their courses and a list of courses with their students? The relationship between courses and students is stored in another table in the database named "join_courses_students."

i get the data from api but i don't know how i can get the relationship from the table and return the list of items

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.